# How do I unwrap a wrapped struct in golang?

Tags: go, struct

So I have been searching and can't seem to find how to get the backend struct for a wrapped struct in go.

This is the use case: I am using [traffic](http://github.com/pilu/traffic) to manage my web app and it uses it's own wrapped version of the `http.Request` as well as several others. the declaration looks like this:

```golang
type Request struct {
    *http.Request
}
```

I am trying to incorporate [go-guardian](http://github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/auth) and I need to send an http.Request to this function:

```golang
    Authenticate(r *http.Request) (Info, error)
```

The question is how do I get the `*http.Request` that the `traffic.Request` was made out of?

I seem to remember seeing a way to do this in a tutorial somewhere but I haven't been able to find it (the problem is I'm not sure I'm using the right term for a wrapped struct).

Any feedback would be graetly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types): `The unqualified type name acts as the field name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embedded field can be accessed using its type name:

```
type Request struct {
    *http.Request
}
```

For the above:

```
func f(r *Request) {
  // This will pass the embedded *http.Request
  g(r.Request)
}
```

Comment: I kept trying `r.(http.Request)` `http.Request(r)` and many variations involving a moving (*) - this worked though. Thank you!